# VLOOKUP with a dynamic range in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm trying to use VLookup in excel on a range that's changing according to a reference number.

I've attached an image as it's far easier to understand.

http://tinypic.com/r/20h53ls/8

What I am attempting is to get the values of item no 1, 2, 3 etc and place them horizontally. However the range (which is defined by the ref) changes.

So in the image I am try to get the value of 1 (which is 21) and place it into E3. I want the value of 1 to be placed all the way down column E until we reach the new ref no. Then the value of 1 is 11. And so on with 2, 3, 4...

I've tried different combinations of MATCH and INDIRECT to try and define the range but without any success.

If anyone has any ideas I would love your thoughts.

Many thanks.

Comment: Am I am missing something here? if you want to stabilize use the $ sign.. is =VLOOKUP(E$1,$C$1:$D$15,2,0) in E2 resolve this? Sorry I did not get this right.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What you seem to be looking for is a variable in lieu of your constant. For example `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A:$E;COLUMNS(Sheet1!$A:$E);FALSE)` which changes as new columns are inserted. For ease of use you may change `$E` to `E` so it will become a simply expandable formula (fill right, etc).

Comment: thanks @user3819867. In the formula you posted, that seems to adjust the columns, however the range is one that moves down dynamically and is defined by the ref no. Is there a way to adjust the range also?

Comment: You can use `MATCH()` formula to find the column index of your index number (or any string or number whatsoever).